# Incompatible argument type error in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, error, compilation

I have installed Magento 2.2.2.

Running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` result in this error:

```
Magento\Backend\Model\View\Layout\GeneratorPool
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Condition\ConditionFactory.php

Actual type: \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface; File: 
vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php
```

In

> vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Condition/ConditionFactory.php:

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Condition;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

/**
 * Factory for composite.
 */
class ConditionFactory
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $elementVisibilityConditions
     *
     * @return Condition
     */
    public function create(array $elementVisibilityConditions)
    {
        $conditions = [];
        foreach ($elementVisibilityConditions as $condition) {
            $conditions[] = $this->objectManager->create($condition['name']);
        }
        return $this->objectManager->create(Condition::class, ['conditions' => $conditions]);
    }
}
```

In

> vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Backend\Model\View\Layout;

use Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure;
use Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure;

/**
 * Pool of generators for structural elements
 */
class GeneratorPool extends \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool
{
    /**
     * @var Filter\Acl
     */
    protected $aclFilter;

    /**
     * @param ScheduledStructure\Helper $helper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Filter\Acl $aclFilter
     * @param array $generators
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScheduledStructure\Helper $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Filter\Acl $aclFilter,
        array $generators = null
    ) {
        $this->aclFilter = $aclFilter;
        parent::__construct(
            $helper,
            $scopeConfig,
            $scopeResolver,
            $logger,
            $generators
        );
    }

    /**
     * Build structure that is based on scheduled structure
     *
     * @param ScheduledStructure $scheduledStructure
     * @param Structure $structure
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function buildStructure(ScheduledStructure $scheduledStructure, Structure $structure)
    {
        parent::buildStructure($scheduledStructure, $structure);
        $this->aclFilter->filterAclElements($scheduledStructure, $structure);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

What is the fix?

Comment: could you show your full code of php class?

Comment: I just did. Check it out.

Comment: Did you do php bin/magento setup:upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just before `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: did you install a fresh Magento2.2 or you upgraded from older version, If you have upgraded Magento from older version you may read this comment here [https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11190#issuecomment-334469162]

Comment: This appears to have been answered here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141731/magento-2-error-during-compilation-incompatible-argument-type and here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193709/magento-2-2-incompatible-argument-type

Comment: @WISAM HAKIM I have installed version 2.2.2 from an archive, as shown in *[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xa5sNcSmyE)*.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir - you are trying to update magento 2 version ? or you are doing fresh installation ?

Comment: @ManthanDave Yes. From a *.zip* file. as shown **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xa5sNcSmyE)**.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir - so question here is magento 2 installed or not ? it is working or not ? - also can you please remove your var/generation and generated directory from the root and then try to run this command ? it will resolved your error for the same

Comment: It is not working. After extracting the archive, I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then `bin/magento setup:di:compile`, which resulted in the error described in the question.

Comment: Can you please check your custom modules for any fields in the construct function where you are defining a variable just like $connection = null inside the construct? Then use something like this \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null.

Comment: @AsheemPatro There is no such file.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be there but [was removed](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8335523e6439352e6ab8b9c987eaa50f8e1c5b3c). Make sure no di.xml still references it. So look for something like this:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool"
    type="Magento\Backend\Model\View\Layout\GeneratorPool" />
```

On the cause:
It looks like you copied Magento 2.2 over an earlier version and something botched your upgrade path. Did you follow [these instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/bk-compman-upgrade-guide.html#upgrade-the-magento-application)?

Comment: What shell I do?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Layout

You can see there is no **GeneratorPool.php** file there

Be sure you are working with stable version, you can download from here https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Answer (score 0):

I removed

> vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php

entirely which then allowed the compile command to process normally.

Got the suggestion from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11190